# Парсинг excel файла с группировкой строк в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, excel

Необходимо распарсить данные excel с группировкой, на выходе желательно получить json.

Пример входных данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе:

```
{"a1":{"b1":["c1","c2","c3"]}}
```

Comment: convert-excel-to-json?

Comment: по поддержке группировки там ничего не нашел